# listview scrolling crashes on only android kitkat 4.4

Tags: android, android-listview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a strange kitkat behaviour, when i scroll listview up and down then suddenly the app crashes, but this occurs only in kitkat, below that version its working fine.

Any idea please help, below is the crash report

```
05-15 12:49:45.814: E/Surface(22053): dequeueBuffer failed (Invalid argument)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053): Could not lock surface
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:243)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2440)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2284)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1914)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1024)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5796)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-15 12:49:45.815: E/ViewRootImpl(22053):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the adapter code

```
public class CommonAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

        Context context;
        int layout;
        List<T> list;
        int position;

        public CommonAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> list) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
            this.context = context;
            this.layout = textViewResourceId;
            this.list = list;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(layout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.parentRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_parent);
                holder.item_tittle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_tittle);
                holder.item_discount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.discount_txt);
                holder.discountLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.discount_layout);
                holder.lined_price = (LinedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lined_price);
                holder.starting_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_starting_price);
                holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contentimage);
                holder.buy_button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bt_buy_now);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.buy_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CommonAdapter.this.position = position;
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.SHOW_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
                    new Thread(fetchProductDetail).start();

                }
            });
            ContentItem contentItem = (ContentItem) list.get(position);
            try {
                holder.item_tittle.setText(contentItem.getTitle_item().replace("&amp;", "&"));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //title is null
                Crashlytics.logException(e);
                holder.item_tittle.setText("Not Available");
                if(contentItem!=null ){

                }
                Crashlytics.log("Item title not available for "+contentItem.getId_item());

            }

            holder.lined_price.setText(contentItem.getMarketing_price_formatted());
            holder.starting_price.setText(contentItem.getStarting_price_formatted());

            holder.parentRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CommonAdapter.this.position = position;
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.SHOW_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
                    new Thread(fetchProductDetail).start();

                }
            });

            String imPath = Utility.getImageRevisedPath(contentItem.getImages().get(0), "L");
            holder.img.setTag(imPath);
            imageLoader.displayImage(imPath, holder.img);
            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView starting_price;
            LinedTextView lined_price;
            TextView item_tittle, item_discount;
            ImageView img;
            Button buy_button;
            LinearLayout discountLayout;
            RelativeLayout parentRelativeLayout;
        }
```

Comment: could you pls add your code of the listview and the adapter

Comment: are you using holder for your list or not ?  if yes then post your code.

Comment: @A.S. updated the my code